# A computer system has RAM of 32K bytes and 64 peripherals. What is the number of distinct addresses required?

Tags: memory, ram, addressing

Is it correct to assume that the number of addresses for 32k of ram is 2^15 addresses? Then for the peripherals is it 2^6 addresses?

Comment: Can somebody explain the downvotes?

Comment: 1. Processor architecture is not really electrical engineering. 2. Your question doesn't really make sense. For one, why are you assuming a peripheral has to map to a address? Is this in a memory-mapped IO context? You need to provide a LOT more information.

Comment: 1. What is the appropriate stack exchange for processor architecture?

Comment: 2. I'm assuming a peripheral has to map to an address because it is indeed memory-mapped, I should have clarified. I'm not sure what more information is required because the question is not specific to a certain computer system.

Comment: There probably is no more appropriate place on SE for a question like this, thanks to the infanticide committed against the beta Embedded site, and given the small scale of address space the OP is referring to.
But yes, you need to provide more detail about the peripherals you're referring to - most peripherals have several "registers" each - whether memory-mapped or i/o-mapped, there's no rules as to how many, it all depends on the complexity of the peripheral(s).

Comment: The problem isn't that this is the wrong site, the problem is that this question is not suitable anywhere on stack exchange.

Comment: 8-bit and 32-bit computers may require different answers to this question.

Answer (score 3):

As posed this question is not answerable. It reeks of an oversimplified homework question that can only be answered in the context of the course it goes with and the assumpetions that course has taught.

> A computer system has RAM of 32K bytes

The word "byte" has two different definitions. The original defintion was "the smallest addressable unit of memory" but sometimes it is uses as a synonym of "octet". If the latter meaning is used then the number of addresses needed will depend on the size of the smallest addressable unit of data (which is not nessacerally the same as the data bus width).

If we assume that "byte" does reffer to the smallest addressable unit of memory (either because that is the definition the asker is using or because your system has 8 bits as it's smallest addresable unit) then yes you will need 2<sup>15</sup> addresses to address your ram. Since most computers nowadays do indeed use 8 bits as their smallest addressable unit this answer is probablly right.

> and 64 peripherals.

This is where it gets really messy. If we assume the perhiperals use one address each then your answer would be correct but most real perhiperals use more than that. How many more varies wildly.

> What is the number of distinct addresses required?

In addition to the above there was no mention of rom in your question, a real computer system is almost certain to have some rom.

And finally note that it would be very weird for a computer system to have a non power of two address space size. It's not entirely clear what is meant by "required" in your question but it would not surprise me if your course expects you to round up to the next power of 2

Comment: love your answer +1'd it ... but the weirdness is not that weird if you live in the FPGA world :) however that may not be the case above